# Add/Remove a class to element in a click on a different div with Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

**html**

```
<body>

  <header>
    <a href="#" id="toggle-button">
      <img src="img/menu_icon.svg">
    </a>
  </header>

  <main id="wrapper">

    <aside id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div></div>
    </aside>

    <section id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </section>

  </main>

</body>
```

I'm not figure out how to achieve the same result describe bellow with Knockout

**JQuery**

```
$('#toggle-button').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $("img", this).toggleClass('rotated');
  $('#wrapper').toggleClass('menu--visible');
});
```

I'm using the css binding, but don't know how to add the classes to other element than #toggle-button as i'm doing 
[here](https://jsfiddle.net/pknoll/rauj5nxw/6/). Any ideas/materials/docs to help me with that??

Answer (score 1):

You could use one `observable` to toggle the classes for both the `img` and the `#wrapper`. You just have to toggle the value of the observable during each click. Use the `css` binding to apply and remove classes based on the value of the observable.

```js
var viewModel = {
toggle : ko.observable(false)
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
.rotated{
transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<body>

  <header>
    <a href="#" id="toggle-button" data-bind="click:function(){toggle(!toggle())}">
      <img src="https://cdn.xl.thumbs.canstockphoto.com/canstock33334848.jpg" data-bind="css: {rotated : toggle() }">
    </a>
  </header>

  <main id="wrapper" data-bind="css: {'menu-visible' : toggle() }">

    <aside id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <div></div>
    </aside>

    <section id="page-content-wrapper">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </section>

  </main>

</body>
```